# Change specific div, nth-child?

Tags: css, html, behavior, css-selectors

I have a problem here. I have this `div` that's mentioned 4 times in my code, like:

```
<div class='box1'>
Hello 1
</div>
<div class='box1'>
Hello 2
</div>
<div class='box1'>
Hello 3
</div>
<div class='box1'>
Hello 4
</div>
```

and I want to do some changes to this `div` class, but only the last one. I cant get the nth-class to work, it seems that i need to make a `ul` table for it to work? Can I get a workaround somewhere in the **CSS** and make it work without having to rewrite my code?

Comment: oh yeah, was is a hurry for a while there, forgot the CSS.. I've been struggling with this small problem for some days now, and somehow i managed to find the help through my own tags when i made the question. Sooo, problem solved!

Comment: Then you should post the answer

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this with the `nth-child` pseudo class. Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m7uW7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering a bit late.

To make any changes to the **Last-DIV**, You just need to simply add a selector i.e, **:last-of-type** a change in the CSS.

Add-on: If it's for **First-DIV**, Add a selector i.e, **first-of-type**

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="box1">
  Hello 1
</div>
<div class="box1">
  Hello 2
</div>
<div class="box1">
  Hello 3
</div>
<div class="box1">
  Hello 4
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.box1:first-of-type {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
}
div.box1:last-of-type {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**Editor:** `https://jsfiddle.net/naheedshareef/09dwtfpu/8/`